# Trigger to update another table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_orderline

AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON ORDERS

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

  INSERT INTO ORDERLINE(orderline_no, qty, order_no, product_no)

  VALUES (ol_no.nextval, :new.qty, :new.order_no, :new.product_no);

END;
```

I am trying to create a trigger that updates orderline table after a new record has been inserted into orders. But I get this error:

```
Error(3,26): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.QTY'

Error(3,51): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.PRODUCT_NO'
```

Comment: Can you give us the structure of the ORDERS table ? and ORDERLINE ?

Comment: @ Xavinou: order_no, employee_no, branch_no, order_date,ship_date, shipping_method,tax_status, subtotal, tax_amt,shipping_charge, total_amt, customer_no

Comment: Can you explain the business logic. Where does the quantity come from ? You might be better off with a stored procedure that encapsulated the insert/updates of order and order_line

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess the orders table does not have columns named 'order_no' and 'product_no'. I can reproduce the error in that case and get the bind variable message. So what is the orders table column names?

UPDATE: there is nothing to get the new value from for order_no or product_no or for that matter qty according to your comment. Where do you expect the values to come from?

UPDATE: Accordin to your update you have the following columns in the orders table:

> order_no,
>   employee_no,
>   branch_no,
>   order_date,
>   ship_date,
>   shipping_method,
>   tax_status,
>   subtotal,
>   tax_amt,
>   shipping_charge,
>   total_amt,
>   customer_no

In that list of columns I do not see product_no or qty. Order_no is there though.

Comment: @ jschoen: I thought the new values would be the ones that got inserted in orders table. So for instance, Say a new row got inserted in orders, then the trigger is supposed to update orderline based on what the new record was. So, the new record will have product no and qty too.

Comment: @ jschoen: Oops! you are right, there is not product_no. So, that means, the product_no has to come from product table

Comment: @tbrown Maybe you are doing this backwards. Maybe your Order line table should have a trigger, that would insert or update the the order table when it is updated. Probably not though. You are probably going to need to move this type of function in to you business logic ode, instead of trying to do it via a trigger.

Comment: @tbrown okay you have the order_no, so put the trigger on your orderline table, and have it update the orders row upon insert or update. That should work. This means the initial order row will need to be already created before you insert an orderline, but it should work.

Comment: @jschoesn: thanks, but the thing is orderline is a bridge table between orders and products. So basically, everytime there is an insert on Orders and products, the orderline table should be updated.

Comment: @tbrown I was thinking this was more like a regular order. You have a list of products in your inventory, customer comes in wants to place order, you create order, then add the individual items as line items to the order, which would update the order total, and decrement the number of products on hand. I am sure I am missing something. But the way I see it, you can not add product_no or qty to the order table, since each order could have multiple products with different quantities.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found.

Look here : http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1556226&page=14

> You have inadvertently discovered why,
>   in the "Oracle World" it is generally
>   bad form to code user-defined names
>   within double quotes. You see,
>   whenever you define a name in Oracle
>   using double quotes and any alpha
>   character that is not UPPER CASE, then
>   you must always use double quotes and
>   the same mixed-case configuration. If
>   you do not use double-quotes, then
>   Oracle presumes that regardless of
>   your case in the code, that your
>   Oracle name is uppercase !
>
> So, when your referred, in your code,
>   to "...INTO   :new.user_idx...",
>   Oracle looks for "USER_IDX", which it
>   cannot find, since you defined that
>   column as *"user_idx"* -- "user_idx"
>   <> "USER_IDX".
>
> If you sanitize your code of all
>   double quotes, then your problem(s)
>   should disappear.

Comment: @ Xavinou: Thanks, but the double quotes is not the issue in my case. I checked my create scripts to make sure. :(